# Почему при использование static в switch происходит ошибка?

Tags: c++, switch, static, case

Почему когда использую статическую переменную в switch case выдает ошибки :
"initialization of "counter" is skipped by 'case' label",
"initialization of "counter" is skipped by 'default' label"

```
        int num = 1;
        switch (num)
        {
        case 1:
            static int counter = 0;
            cout << "COUNTER = " << counter;
            counter++;
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "000";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Error";
            break;
        }
```

Эту ошибку можно исправить путём перемещения статической переменной в самый низ, но почему c++ не допускает указанной ситуации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что конструкция `switch`/`case` в С++ является модифицированным оператором `goto`, и блоки `case` не создают новую область видимости. Соответственно переменная `counter` может быть использована в блоках `case 0` и `default`, но инициализация этой переменной происходит только при выполнении блока `case 1`. Это может привести к использованию переменной `couter` без инициализации.

Следует вручную создать новую область видимости. Теперь `counter` не виден из других блоков и не может быть случайно использован внутри них:

```
case 1:
{
   static int counter = 0;
   cout << "COUNTER = " << counter;
   counter++;
   break;
}
```

Или вынести эту переменную наружу, тогда `counter` может быть использован и в других блоках, но всегда будет инициализирован.

```
static int counter = 0;
switch (num)
```